# JavaFX 8 Can't access to final object from anonymous class

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a method to show an alert with code:

[image]

But I get the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class smpb.ui.SMPBUICore$2 from class smpb.ui.SMPBUICore
    at smpb.ui.SMPBUICore.createAlert(SMPBUICore.java:138)
    at smpb.ui.SMPBUICore.showAlert(SMPBUICore.java:117)
    at smpb.ui.components.systemdirectories.SMPBSystemDirectoriesComponent.checkTableExistsAction(SMPBSystemDirectoriesComponent.java:206)
    ... 38 more
```

Why?

p.s.
I am using NetBeans 7.4

Comment: Which class is `smpb.ui.SMPBUICore`?

Comment: Are you on debug mode? It maybe caused by hot deploy. Try to stop your app, and clean&rebuild the **whole** project.